# Postfix SMTP errors when connecting from another machine

Tags: postfix, smtp

I have a Postfix server, and a client on another machine.

When I am on the Postfix machine and I send an email using telnet, if there is an error, like a relay access denied, I get the error *immediately*.

Example

```
HELO vincent
250 foo.cc
MAIL FROM: vincent@bar.it
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO: fakeemail@gmail.com
554 5.7.1 <fakeemail@gmail.com>: Relay access denied
```

But if I connect to the server from another machine, then I don't receive theses errors directly. Instead, I will get them as a bounce.

Example

```
HELO vincent
250 foo.cc
MAIL FROM: vincent@bar.it
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO: fakeemail@gmail.com
250 2.1.5 Ok
```

Can I somehow force postfix to send errors directly to my client ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postfix is generating a bounce, rather than a reject, because it accepted the mail for delivery but could not deliver it. This the expected behavior for both `postfix` and the `smtp` protocol.

As to why postfix is accepting the message from the remote machine, but not localhost I can't tell without setting the settings in `main.cf`/`postconf`.